# Shipment emails not being sent even though other emails are working Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, shipment-tracking

I'm running into an issue where Magento 2.3.4 is not sending the shipment confirmation email after I enter the shipment for an order.

I have tried to send the shipping details (by checking the box to send customer notification) and it does not send.

If I go into the Admin page, go to Sales > Orders, pull up the shipment, and then click "Send Tracking Information", the email is also does not send.

When I press "Send Tracking Information" it asks me for confirmation "Do you really want to send the customer an e-mail of the order" and then the screen remains blank with a text "Sent by Shipment Number".

Debug.log & cron.log

```
main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_shipment_emails is run [] []
main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_shipment_emails is successfully finished
```

When I place an order, the order confirmation email is sent correctly.

When I invoice the order, the invoice email is sent correctly.

Why are the shipment emails not being sent when a shipment is entered?

Comment: which theme are you using?

Comment: Check Magneto log files, is there anything mension there?

Comment: My theme is Codazon Fastest in its latest version https://themeforest.net/item/fastest-magento-2-themes-magento-212-magento-19-multipurpose-responsive-theme-10-design/16178989

Comment: No, In the cron.log and debug.log files it only indicates "Cron Job sales_send_order_shipment_emails is successfully finished." and in the system.log file it does not make any call to send email or shipment

Comment: check if your theme is overriding the shipment email template. If so try removing the template or compare it with the core templates for changes.

Comment: @paj Thanks for your reply, the problem was in the theme.
Changing the site to the luma template works perfectly. Now I have to fix the shipping template problem in my theme.

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25221

Problem caused by customized e-mail templates based on previous versions.

If you have customized e-mail templates inserting track.phtml this way:

```
{{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='frontend' template='MyParcelNL_Magento::email/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
```

Try changing that to this so it uses the layout XML:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_track" shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
```

Otherwise track.phtml doesn't receive the (new) argument containing the TrackingUrl object argument defined in the layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @paj

I had already tried that solution and it didn't work properly.

I found the solution that works perfectly.

1. Create an email Shipment template with the standard format.
2. Review it to include {{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_track" shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
3. Once the template Shipment is saved, access the DDBB and in the table email_template modify is_legacy to 1
4. Assign the created template to shipments in Stores > Settings > Sales > Sales Email.

So if you get the full email with the tracking number

**But there's something I don't like at all.**

In the email it indicates the url of the follow up that I have put in magento
[image]

but the link, does not lead to that url, it leads to a url of my site that comes out blank whit text "TRACKING INFORMATION"

**I worked around this problem by just replacing** \vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\email\shipment\track.phtml

This code:

```
<a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getTrackingUrl()->getUrl($_item)) ?>" target="_blank"> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?> </a>
```

by:

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?>
```